# DataTable-FixedHeader on ASP.Net Repeater throws errors after async postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fixed-header-tables

I use the FixedHeader-function (http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/) from DataTables (http://datatables.net/) on an ASP Repeater.

The repeater/table is not visible when the page is loaded, the user has to select an item in a dropdownlist for the repeader to be databound.

The scripts are added as ScriptReferences in the scriptmanager.

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/FixedHeader.min.js" />
```

The code for initiating the table is done when the page/post-back is complete using:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Initialization: (Only then the table exists)

```
if ($('#myid').length > 0)
fixedHeaderList = new FixedHeader(document.getElementById('myid'), {
    "offsetTop": 36
});
```

This works perfectly fine.

I have added a asp-button that does nothing, within an update panel just to get a postback. And after this, it failes when I try to scroll on the following line:

```
fnSumScroll: function (f, e) {
    var d = f[e]; <--
    ...
```

(It does not matter if I recreated the fixed header or not. (new FixedHeader...))

I have also tried to execute fnUpdate on the FixedHeader-object after an asp postback,
    fixedHeaderList.fnUpdate()

But that only leads to a javascript error:

```
'$lineinfo' is undefined
```

Any ideas at all?

Comment: I've created a simple demo-website to illustrate the problem. It seems to be working in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. In IE, the following javascript error is returned: "Unhandled exception at line 87, column 50 in http://datatables.net/download/build/FixedHeader.nightly.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'nodeName' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: The demo-site: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5161213/FixedHeaderTest.zip , Click on loadData to populate the table and apply FixedHeaders, then on doPostback do make a postback. If you scroll in IE after this, the problem occurs.